# Control IE as another user from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

My sccenario is as follows:
I have an excel workbook that does a lot of stuff, like create users and such.
A part of this "create user"-procedure is to edit some info on a website.
BUT this website needs to be launched as another user which has access to it.
I have no problem controlling IE if I launch it normally with the current user. But when I launch IE as another user, I cant take control of it from Excel.

I have done a lot of googling and tried a lot of stuff.

Fx. code from the following sources:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/using-vba-to-automate-internet-explorer-sessions-from-an-excel-spreadsheet/

http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml

http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/iedom.shtml

None of which has worked in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good workaround here: https://superuser.com/a/49462

Basically I found out that it's possible to force a loginprompt on pages using Windows Authentication, and then log in as a different user.

That means that the IE process still runs as my user, thus making it possible to take control of the window from Excel.